# Antd v3 change caret color on Tooltip

Tags: tooltip, antd

Anyone knows how to customize the caret of the Tooltip on Antd v3?

On docs https://3x.ant.design/components/tooltip/ there's only API for placement but not for styles of the caret, just styles of the tooltip per se.

I know that the class of the arrow is `.ant-tooltip-arrow`, I can change the background of the arrow, but not the color of the caret. I tried with `border` , `color`, `background` but nothing works (currently is black, that arrow inside the red square which is the background):

[image]

The "Computed" styles of the div with class `ant-tooltip-arrow` is this one:

```
background-attachment scroll
background-clip border-box
background-color rgb(255, 0, 0)
background-image none
background-origin padding-box
background-position-x 0%
background-position-y 0%
background-repeat-x
background-repeat-y
background-size auto
border-top-color rgb(173, 255, 47)
border-top-style none
border-top-width 0px
bottom -5.07107px
box-sizing border-box
color rgb(255, 255, 255)
white .ant-tooltip-arrow
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) .ant-tooltip
#212529 body
#212529 body
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) body
display block
font-family BogleWeb-Regular, serif
font-feature-settings "tnum", "tnum"
font-size 14px
14px !important .ant-tooltip-arrow
14px .ant-tooltip
1rem body
0.88rem !important body
1rem body
14px body
font-variant-caps normal
font-variant-east-asian normal
font-variant-ligatures normal
font-variant-numeric tabular-nums
font-weight 400
height 13.0711px
left 13px
letter-spacing normal
line-height 21px
list-style-image none
list-style-position outside
list-style-type none
overflow-x hidden
overflow-y hidden
pointer-events none
position absolute
text-align left
text-size-adjust 100%
visibility visible
width 13.0711px
-webkit-tap-highlight-color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change the color of caret, you can use `color` property on tootip to specify the color for caret and then use `overlayInnerStyle` property to pass a styles object which will contain a **backgroundColor** where you can specify the color of your tooltip card eg-

> overlayInnerStyle = {{ backgroundColor: "black" }}

What happens is `color` property set the background color of the whole tooltip and then you override the background color of card using `overlayInnerStyle`

Answer (score 0):

With before:

```
.ant-tooltip-arrow::before {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  // etc
}
```